# Resolve conflict between System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Common

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, system.drawing, spreadsheetlight, system.drawing.common

I am trying to add SpreadSheetLight to a new Dnn v9.10.2 project running on Windows Server 2019, but I get a runtime error saying

> CS0433: The type 'Image' exists in both 'System.Drawing.Common,
> Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and
> 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

when I copy the dlls into the bin folder. I have a file that was using System.Drawing, but it was using the full namespace in it's references. I tried updating those to System.Drawing.Common, but it instead throws the error

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the
> namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Commenting out the lines of code using System.Drawing resolved the runtime error, but ultimately when trying a simple test of just opening and closing a blank workbook it throws the exception

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing is not supported
> on this platform.

I haven't been able to find much on how to fix this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is happening to me with two projects, one is written in .net standard 2.0, the other one is .net framework 4.6.2. I am using aliases, but I can't use the method (containing a parameter of System.Drawing.Image) of .net standard 2.0 project in .net framework, because I have to use System.Drawing.Common -> .net standard build when I use this method. But I can't use, because it is not compatible with System.Drawing.Image of System.Drawing.Common.dll

Answer (score 1):

Upon first glance it seems that this library is a .NET 3.5 library and DNN Platform 9.10.2 is .NET Framework 4.7.2 you are most likely hitting a compatibility issue with changes in .NET 4.7.

It looks like the source for SpereadSheetLight is available, you could try to recompile it for .NET 4.7.2 and see if you can clear the issue.